# Firewall configuration worksheet?

Tags: firewall

Are there any available "worksheets" out there (in Excel, PDF, etc. format) to help in planning firewall configuration? Looking for some way to systematically keep track of the machines, ports, etc. while planning how to set up an environment. I'm specifically using Windows Firewall, but a general-purpose worksheet would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching around, you would think this would be more common.  Here's one from the NIST for host/firewall configuration - [HCW Firewall Worksheet](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SMA/fasp/documents/network_security/HCW_Firewall_Worksheet_071107.doc).  You can take bits and pieces that you need and compile your own that's best suited for your needs.

Comment: Please do not post shortened URLs.